# Excluding from case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have got this query:

```
select 
    case when EventCategory < 0.05 Then 'NOT INCL' ELSE 'OK' END AS Under3Min
from
(
    Select   
    Sum(case when CustomEvent = 'without Stop' then cast(EventEndDateTime - EventStartDateTime as float)*24 else 0 end) as EventCategory
    FROM tDataCategory
```

In this query I take from the table CustomEvent the `without Stop´ and take the sum of this duration. And in the first select I said if EventCategory is less than 0,05 then it should not included else include.
And this gave me the right output. But I would like to exclude the "not Included" complete in the output.
How can I exclude this issue?

Comment: `WHERE  EventCategory >= 0.05`?

Comment: :) thanks, that was really easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Where condition,

```
select 
    CustomEvent,
    case when EventCategory < 0.05 Then 'NOT INCL' ELSE 'OK' END AS Under3Min
from
(
    Select   
        CustomEvent,
        Sum(case when CustomEvent = 'without Stop' then cast(EventEndDateTime - EventStartDateTime as float)*24 else 0 end) as EventCategory
    FROM tDataCategory
    GROUP BY CustomEvent
) x
WHERE CustomEvent <> 'without Stop' 
    OR (CustomEvent = 'without Stop' AND x.EventCategory >=0.05)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But now I realized that the other Events in the table EventCategory not appears. Only `without stops` appears. What can I do to display every events in that table?

Comment: @M.JAY, I have edited the answer to get other events.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    case when EventCategory < 0.05 Then 'NOT INCL' ELSE 'OK' END AS Under3Min
from
(
    Select   
    Sum(case when CustomEvent = 'without Stop' then cast(EventEndDateTime - EventStartDateTime as float)*24 else 0 end) as EventCategory
    FROM tDataCategory Where (CustomEvent = 'without Stop' AND cast(EventEndDateTime - EventStartDateTime as float)*24 >=0.05) OR CustomEvent != 'without Stop'
) x
```